# Can't connect to mysql database outside aws vm after creating succesfully

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, virtual-machine

I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04) article to setup mysql server in my aws vm. At the time of creation of the vm itself I had allowed inbound traffic to port 3306 from all ip addresses.

After creating an admin account, I cannot access the account from outside the vm using sql workbench. I made changes in the property file to change the bind-address to 0.0.0.0 so that remote connections maybe allowed from outside. That also did not help.
What am I missing here? I did everything and still it won't connect. Appreciate any help on the matter.
[AWS Security Groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90bKc.png)

Comment: What are the secuirty groups for the instance?

Comment: added a screenshot of the aws security groups

Comment: What error do you get when you try connect externally?

Comment: Your connection attempt failed for user 'myadmin' to the MySQL server at {ip}:3306:
This error occurs instantly too, within 2 seconds

Comment: The link you gave grants access only to localhosts `'sammy'@'localhost'`. Have you modified that to allow external access?

Comment: I wrote exactly that same line. For remote, what should I replace 'localhost' with?

Comment: DO has also [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-mysql) about that.

Comment: It worked! That was the underlying issue. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was that mysql was setup to allow access from `localhost`. To solve the problem, external access needed to be allowed. This can be done by following the guide:

- [How To Allow Remote Access to MySQL](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-mysql)